# problems when setup a python package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to install the python package "pip" to my server. But I got a problem when downloading the source code. The entire information is listed below.

```
    [map@host.com ~]$ easy_install pip      
    Searching for pip
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [Errno 218603680]_ssl.c:554: error:0D07A0A0:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_copy:unknown format -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
    Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 218603680] _ssl.c:554: error:0D07A0A0:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_copy:unknown format -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or download links found for pip
    error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

I also tried to install some other packages, such as nose, distribute, and got the same mistake. BTW, I used SecureCRT to ssh the server.
Is this a problem about OpenSSL? How could I install pip successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's wrong with `easy_install`, but this is how I've installed pip on linux:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum search nginx
yum -y install python-pip
yum install libxslt-devel libxml2-devel
yum install gcc
yum install python-devel
echo 'alias pip="/usr/bin/pip-python"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

This is for Fedora.
For Ubuntu you might need to install the above libraries only use `apt-get install` instead of `yum`

Comment: Umm, you don't need all this for pip.

Comment: Well, you need all for this for pip if you don't have them installed by default. I had the unfortunate luck to not have all of these dependencies and with a lot of google-ing stuff, I ended up installing  pip just as above. I agree, most of the stuff might not need, if they come by default

Comment: "yum search nginx" - I can categorically confirm that that step is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your distribution's package manager to install pip.

- On Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
- On Fedora/RedHat: `sudo yum install python-pip`

To install it manually:

1. Download the source installer from the [pypi entry for `pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). Scroll down to find the installer. Here is a [direct link](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=6afbb46aeb48abac658d4df742bff714) to version 1.4.1 (current at this time).
2. Expand the archive: `tar xvzf pip-1.4.1.tar.gz`
3. Run the setup script `sudo python pip-1.4.1/setup.py install`